# code hangs up after some period while comparing datetime

Tags: datetime, python-2.7

I have the following code which hangs after some period while comparing datetime. Following is my code.

```
def worker():
flag = True
while True:
    s1 = '101:35:00'
    e1 = '101:36:00'
    s2 = '101:37:00'
    e2 = '101:38:00'
    s3 = '101:39:00'
    e3 = '101:40:00'

    if int(s1[0]) == 1:
        start1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + s1[1:9]
    else:
        start1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) + ' ' + s1[1:9]

    if int(s2[0]) == 1:
        start2 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + s2[1:9]
    else:
        start2 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) + ' ' + s2[1:9]

    if int(s3[0]) == 1:
        start3 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + s3[1:9]
    else:
        start3 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) + ' ' + s3[1:9]

    if int(e1[0]) == 1:
        end1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + e1[1:9]
    else:
        end1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) + ' ' + e1[1:9]

    if int(e2[0]) == 1:
        end2 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + e2[1:9]
    else:
        end2 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) + ' ' + e2[1:9]

    if int(e3[0]) == 1:
        end3 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + ' ' + e3[1:9]
    else:
        end3 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)) + ' ' + e3[1:9]

    s1t = datetime.datetime.strptime(start1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    s2t = datetime.datetime.strptime(start2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    s3t = datetime.datetime.strptime(start3, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    e1t = datetime.datetime.strptime(end1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    e2t = datetime.datetime.strptime(end2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    e3t = datetime.datetime.strptime(end3, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    cur = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    curr = datetime.datetime.strptime(cur, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    if e1t < curr <= s2t or e2t < curr <= s3t:
        flag = False

    else: pass

    while not flag:
        print 'iwashereghgj'
        print str(curr) #line1
        if s2t <= curr < e2t or s3t <= curr < e3t:          
            q1.put(True)

            flag = True
        else:
            flag = True
```

For example in this case the code just hangs up after curr reaches '2014-01-06 01:37:00' at line1. Anyone can help me out why it is happening like this?

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: You have `while True` loop with no `break/return/raise`, so how do you expect it to escape the loop?

Comment: But my question is why code hangs at #line1 just after 2 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of that duplication makes your code very difficult to debug. Start with some encapsulation:

```
def process_time(timestring):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    h, m, s = map(int, timestring[1:9].split(':'))
    time = datetime.time(hour=h, minute=m, second=s)
    if timestring[0] == '1':
        return datetime.datetime.combine(today, time)
    return datetime.datetime.combine(tomorrow, time)
```

Now it is clear what the function is actually doing and you can skip straight to

```
s1t = process_time(s1) # and so on
```

Plus it feels like you could shorten

```
cur = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
curr = datetime.datetime.strptime(cur, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

to

```
curr = datetime.datetime.now()
```

As for your problem, it's that you don't update `curr` in your loop, so it remains the time at which you started doing your task. You need to keep checking the *current* time.

To implement:

```
# process time strings once, outside loop
timeslots = [(s1t, e1t), ...]
while True:
##    starting = True
    while any(s <= datetime.datetime.now() < e for s, e in timeslots):
##        if starting:
##            print("Starting:", datetime.datetime.now())
##            starting = False
        q1.put(True) # do task in timeslots
    if all(datetime.datetime.now() >= e for s, e in timeslots):
##        print("All timeslots done:", datetime.datetime.now())
        break
# whatever happens afterwards
```

Note: lines starting `##` are for demo purposes, leave commented out for "production" use.

Comment: @user2673943: to avoid breakage around DST, you could use UTC time: `today = datetime.utcnow().date()`, `curr = datetime.utcnow()` assuming `from datetime import datetime`.